# Spring, redirect from index.html to root

Tags: java, spring

Now, when I open root `/` URL I see `index.html` content, but URL is `/`

And when I open `/index.html` I see same, and URL is `/index.html`

I need to see same URL when I open `/` and `/index.html`, so I thought that I need to add a redirect:

```
registry
    .addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    .addRedirectViewController("/index.html", "/");
```

but it seems to circular calls.

How can I do, that `/` and `/index.html` are show same content from same URL `/` with my config?

Part of webapp directory:

[image]

Part of config:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .addResourceHandler("/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/webapp/")
        .setCachePeriod(604800)
        .resourceChain(true)
        .addResolver(new GzipResourceResolver())
        .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
}
```

**UPD**

I tried suggestion from @Asgeirr answer before ask a question, but I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Maybe problem in my server config?

```
@Bean
public Server server(ApplicationContext rootCtx){
    Server server = new Server(serverPort);

    HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
    httpConfig.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

    ServerConnector httpConnector = new ServerConnector(server, new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig));

    httpConnector.setPort(serverPort);
    httpConnector.setIdleTimeout(connectorIdleTime);
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{httpConnector});

    ServletContextHandler apiHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
    apiHandler.setContextPath("/");
    apiHandler.setResourceBase(".");

    HashSessionIdManager idManager = new HashSessionIdManager();
    server.setSessionIdManager(idManager);
    HashSessionManager manager = new HashSessionManager();
    manager.setMaxInactiveInterval(sessionTimeout);
    SessionHandler sessions = new SessionHandler(manager);
    apiHandler.setHandler(sessions);

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webCtx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    webCtx.setServletContext(apiHandler.getServletContext());
    webCtx.register(WebConfiguration.class);
    webCtx.setParent(rootCtx);
    webCtx.refresh();

    // Adding gzip compression
    FilterHolder holder = new FilterHolder(GzipFilter.class);
    holder.setInitParameter("deflateCompressionLevel", "9");
    holder.setInitParameter("minGzipSize", "0");
    holder.setInitParameter("mimeTypes", "text/html,text/css,image/svg+xml,text/xhtml,text/plain,text/xml," +
            "text/javascript,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,application/javascript,application/json");
    apiHandler.addFilter(holder, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));

    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
    apiHandler.addFilter(new FilterHolder(characterEncodingFilter), "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
    apiHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DispatcherServlet(webCtx)), "/");

    HandlerCollection handlerCollection = new HandlerCollection();
    handlerCollection.addHandler(apiHandler);
    server.setHandler(handlerCollection);

    return server;
}
```

Network log, when I call `/index.html`

[image]

Comment: nice question @denis

Comment: You need a redirect not a forward. Forwarding is server side and doesn't change the URL, a redirect will tell the client to make a new get request at the redirected URL and changes the URL.

Comment: My idea is move your main content to another HTML page like `home.html`. Use index.html just to redirect to that page. Give the redirection code alone in the `index.html`.

Comment: @Arun, yes, this way works, but it's a hack, I want to know the problem's parent. Using the way from @Asgeirr answer I get infinitely redirect from `/` to `/` as on the picture in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a redirect.

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .addViewController("/").setViewName("redirect:/index.html");
}
```

Comment: No, I need conversely.
If I enter URL: `localhost/` -> I see content of index.html file from webapp dir.
And if I enter URL `localhost/index.html` -> I will get redirect to `localhost/` and see the content of index.html from webapp

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect in the getmapping like so:

```
@GetMapping("/index.html")
public String getIndex() {
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

and the getter for root would look like:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String getIndex() {
    return "index.html";
}
```

or remove the forwarding from your suggested addViewControllers to get rid of the infinite circular calls:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index.html");
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/index.html", "/");
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but it'll make an infinetely cycle

Comment: It doesn't unless you add another redirect/forward or keep the ones you've set up. Neither of my suggestions goes in circles.

Comment: I tried this before writing the question. I have ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in browser. Maybe, problem in my server config?

Comment: I added my server config to question

Comment: Have you removed the forward:index.html from the root mapping? If so I'm sorry but I can't see why it's going in circles.